# How to list all unit tests with their output in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, mstest

Visual Studio 2015 provides a "Test Explorer" window.  From here, you can click to run tests.  After the tests run, it shows a table with the green/red pass/fail indicator, the name of each test, and the amount of time it took to run.

After running my tests, I can click on a test and the output from that test will appear in a panel below.

What if I want to see a table showing all tests and their outputs so that I don't have to click thru them one-by-one?  It seems like there ought to be a sensible way to do this, as well as export them into a flatfile.

Comment: What is the underlying unit test framework you are using?

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to export your results out from the IDE in VS2015. However you can achieve this via the command line.

1. Open a command prompt and browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE.
2. Type the follwoing command: mstest /testcontainer:[Unit test project dll file path] /resultsfile:[Output Folder Path]\result.trx

I've attached an example:
[image]

You can evaluate that flat-file (XML) any way you'd want. It is verbose. But, basically you're searching for any instance of outcome="Failed" in the `<Results>` nodes.  You'll see what I'm saying when you see the actual file.

Comment: Let me know if this helped or not.